# Canvas rotate rectangle like big wheel

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

So I have a level and want the x,y of a rect to move around like a big wheel.
I am going to use it as a platform to reach the end point.
So every frame it moves 1 or 2 pixels.
Just wondering how to go about this?

I can do a diamond shape easily enough by for 50 loops the x would be ++; and the y would 
be ++;
then after 50 the x would be --; and the y would be ++; and so on.

How is a circle done?

Answer (score 3):

Not quite sure what you are trying to do, but if I understand the question right, you should store the current angle of the rectangle, `theta`, and then update `x` and `y` as `r*sin(theta)+offset_x` and `r*cos(theta)+offset_y` where the offsets are the position of the centre of rotation.  Then each frame increase `theta` by some small amount.

Comment: +1 So close! var newX=centerX+radius*Math.cos(angle); and var newY=centerY+radius*Math.sin(angle);